# Why is $Tor_0^R(M,N)=0$?

Tags: homological-algebra

Suppose we have the following free resolution of a module $N$ $$0\dots\to F_2\to F_1\to F_0\to N\to 0 $$

By definition, this free resolution is exact. Now we tensor this by a module $M$. We get $$\dots\to M\otimes F_2\to M\otimes F_1\to M\otimes F_0\to M\otimes N\to 0$$

> Why is $Tor_0^R(N)=M\otimes N$?

The kernel of $\partial: M\otimes F_0\to M\otimes N$ cannot be the whole of $M\otimes N$ right?

Comment: To compute Tor, you use the chain complex formed by the terms $M \otimes F_i$: you remove $M \otimes N$. So the relevant chain complex ends with $M \otimes F_0 \to 0$.

Comment: The title for this question is probably not was intended: did you mean $M \otimes N$ instead of $0$ on the right hand side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\text{Tor}_0^R(M,N)\simeq M\otimes_R N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117040/texttor-0rm-n-simeq-m-otimes-r-n) and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079688/why-does-mathrmtor-0rm-n-cong-m-otimes-r-n

Comment: (for the question in the body, not in the title)